# Error:index out of range

Tags: python, indexing, error-handling

```
x=int(input("limit"))
n=[]
for i in range (x):
 k=input("number to add")
 n.append(k)
print "to pop the multiples of five"
print n
for no in n:
 if (no%5==0):
  n.pop(no)

print n
```

I get pop index out of range but as far as I check there's is no mistake.. please help me,quick

Comment: You're modifying the same container you're iterating over. This is generally a "Bad Thing"™. Make a *copy* of it to iterate over.

Comment: Or use a list comprehension: `n = [no for no in n if no % 5 > 0]`

Answer (score 0):

**Explaintion**

[You are using `pop()` wrong.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) `pop(x)` takes an argument and pops or removes that index, not item. So when you `pop(5)` you aren't popping a 5 from the list, you are popping the index `5`. That's why you are getting an index out of range error. Try this (note that this is still wrong but it's for the sake of teaching what pop does):

```
x = [1,2,3,4,9,10,10,10]
for i,no in enumerate(x):
 if (no%5==0):
  x.pop(i)

print(x) #prints out : [1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10]
```

[`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) basically takes a list or dictionary or tuple and returns the index and the item in that index. Example:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,9]
for index, item in enumerate(x):
  print("index {}, item {}".format(index,item))
```

prints out:

```
index 0, item 1
index 1, item 2
index 2, item 3
index 3, item 4
index 4, item 9
```

Using `enumerate()` we can get the index and still test the value and change things with it such as `pop()`-ing it. Now this is a bad idea to change a list while we are going through it. Why?

The problem of modifying a container (in this case `pop()`ing a `list`) while you are iterating through it (looping through it) is that you might drop values. Here's an example:

```
alist = [5, 6, 7]
for index, value in enumerate(alist):
    del alist[index]
print(alist)
# Out: [6]
```

Why does it only contain `[6]` after the loop and not an empty list? Well the first iteration it removes the first item which is the `5` in index 0. That's nice but now the list is `[6,7]`, `6` being in the index slot 0. When the next loop happens, `7` is in the index slot `1`, since reduce the size of the list by one each time. And thus we skipped the value `6` in slot 0. After the second loop, we finish the for loop since there's nothing left to loop.

**Solution**

```
n = [1,2,3,4,9,10,10,10]
new_list = []
for no in n:
 if (no%5!=0):
  new_list.append(no)

print n # gives [1, 2, 3, 4, 9]
```

Make a new list, and add values to that list based on your condition, since you wanted to remove items that are `x % 5 == 0` we can add items if it's not equal to zero.

If you want something more "Pythonic" or fancy or one liner you could just do:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,9,10,10,10]
new_list = [a for a in x if a % 5 != 0]
print(new_list)
```

It's called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Very useful in Python.

Answer (score 0):

As Graham said you are using list in wrong way. below code can give you better idea.

```
x=int(input("limit"))
n=[]
for i in range (x):
 k=input("number to add")
 n.append(k)
print "to pop the multiples of five"
print n
for no in n:
 if (no%5==0):
   n.pop(n.index(no)) # remove index of element you want to remove
print n
```